# How do authentication in Vue JS with Laravel so that user cannot enter in his page from URL without login

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-6

Please Help! I want to authenticate my app, so that user cannot enter through URL in the browser to user panel without login, how can I do it in Vue.js and Laravel? If he write the URL like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/users even if he did not put his credencials in login page

Bellow is my code:

```
  AppController


<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//use illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Auth;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
/**vc pode pegar o usuário logado de várias formas, usando  Auth::user(), usando helper auth()->user() e também pela request fazendo $request->user(); ou pela fachada da request tb, Request::user(); */
class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function init(){
        $user = Auth::user();
        //$user = auth()->user();
        return response()->json(['user' => $user], 200);
    }
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], true)) {
            return response()->json(Auth::user(), 200);
        }
        else{
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Could not allow you in. Sorry'], 401);
        }
    }
    public function register(Request $request)
    {   
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        if (isset($user->id)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'User already exist.'], 401);
        }
        $user = new User();

        $user->name = $request->name;        
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
        $user->save();

        Auth::login($user);

        return response()->json($user, 200);
    }
    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
    }
}
```

Vue template LOGIN:

```
<script>
export default {
   name: 'login', 
   props:['app'],
   data(){
       return {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            errors: [],
       }
   },
   methods: {
       onSubmit(){
           this.errors = [];

           if(!this.email){
               this.errors.push('Email is require.');
           }
           if(!this.password){
               this.errors.push('Password is require.');
           }

           if(!this.errors.length){
              const data = {
                    email : this.email,
                    password : this.password
              }
              this.app.req.post('auth/login' , data).then(response => {
                  this.app.user = response.data;
                  //this.$eventHub.$emit('onSubmit', this.MainHeader);
                  this.$router.push('/users');
                  //this.app.MainHeader = 'main-header';
                console.log(this.app.MainHeader);
              }).catch(error => {
                  this.errors.push(error.response.data.error);
              });
           }
       }
   }
}
</script>
```

app.js file

```
   const router = new VueRouter({
    //mode: 'history',
    routes // short for `routes: routes`
})
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
      // this route requires auth, check if logged in
      // if not, redirect to login page.
      if (!auth.loggedIn()) {
        next({
          path: '/login',
          query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
        })
      } else {
        next()
      }
    } else {
      next() // make sure to always call next()!
    }
  });
```

Routers

```
path: '/users',
component:  Users,
name: 'users',
meta:{requiresAuth:true},
children: [
    {
      path: 'dashboard',
      component: Dashboard,
      name: 'dashboard'
    },
```

}

Comment: Its not clear what you mean exactly and you dont show any of your routes. That said, if want a particular route to only allow authenticated users access, you can add the "auth" middleware to that route and Laravel will automatically redirect unauthenticated users back to the login page if they navigate to that url

Comment: @WesleySmith, can u take look again in my question?

Comment: In the browser when i write this url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/users, I want to push the user to login page

Comment: exactly, if you add the `auth` middleware to the route definition in laravel, itll do just just that. Can you show the code you use to create the /users route?

Comment: @WesleySmith, only route that i have are these: http://prntscr.com/rm8k6j . For the user I redirect it after login component vue.

Comment: you must also have a /user route, or it wouldnt work, that route needs to have the auth middleware. add that and itll work as intended

Comment: @WesleySmith, Can u just explain me how do it or show with example?

Comment: Ive added an answer showing what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You dont show your /users route so we cant show you the exact change you need. That said, you need to apply the `auth` middleware to that route. Something like this is what you want:

You'll need to update the namespace and controller names of course

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['web','auth'],  // <---- note the auth middleware here 
    'namespace'  => 'App\Http\Controllers',
],
    static function () {
        Route::get('/users', 'UserController@render')->name('users');
    }
);
```